# Springdoc openapi and Spring boot parent 2.7.10 compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I upgraded my applications `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to 2.7.10.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.10</version>
</parent>

<properties>
   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<properties>
```

Along with this I integrated my app to OpenApi for which I added dependency like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

After this I'm able to access my swagger here `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs` but I can see it as `JSON` response. To get the typical swagger ui page I was recommended to add below dependency while removing the `springdoc-openapi-ui`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I even tried using below dependency yet I get the same error

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my Swagger configuration class

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPIConfig() {
    return new OpenAPI().info(buildInfo());
}

private Info buildInfo() {
    return new Info()
            .title("WTS-Config Shipper Preferences API")
            .description("Shipper Preference API to create rules");
}
```

Now when I run the app in local I'm getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springdoc/core/conditions/MultipleOpenApiSupportCondition has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

My project is currently using `Java 1.8` and I'm running this app in `IntelliJ IDEA` and I made sure all the settings are set to Java8 including the compiler etc. In fact I do not have any other java versions installed in my mac.

My goal is to access the application with Swagger UI: `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

Comment: As per exception message seems `MultipleOpenApiSupportCondition` class was  compiled using Java 17.  Did you try running with JDK 17?

Comment: @ArnauAregall My application is not compatible with JdK 17. In any case when I don't have JDK 17 installed how can it compile with that?

Comment: I would try to run the application without IntelliJ using `mvn clean bootRun` to double check you run the app with the JDK. And also as we are on July 23 I strongly recommend you to upgrade your application to JDK 17 at least.

Comment: @sai23 did you resolve the issue? I'm facing exactly the same issue. My app is in Java 8 as well.

Comment: @Viki, No I gave up on this.. Please update this post if you find any working solution.

Comment: @sai23 in my case, I replaced `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api` with   `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
   </dependency>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` and `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api` dependencies only support JDK 17 and Spring Boot 3.x.
If you want to use Spring Boot 2.x, please use `springdoc-openapi-ui` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration, you should be able to use the `springdoc-openapi-ui` dependency in your Spring Boot 2.x project for integrating OpenAPI documentation with your application.

- `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api` is for Spring-Boot 3.x.versions.

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for Springboot v3. use this. [https://springdoc.org/](https://springdoc.org/v1/)

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

for springboot version <3: use https://springdoc.org/v1/

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
```